# Magento2 Install using composer

Tags: magento2

i want to install magento2 using composer i have upload composer.json file in my root folder now what command i run to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/composer.html) which explain in detail how to install magento using composer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just install composer first in your system using below command

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php mv composer.phar
>   /usr/local/bin/composer

Then you need to run composer command for install magento2

> composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/
>   magento/project-community-edition .

Then Run for install it from browser or use below command

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
--base-url="http://yoururl.com/" 
--db-host="localhost" 
--db-name="dbname" 
--db-user="dbuser" 
--db-password="dbpass" 
--admin-firstname="admin" 
--admin-lastname="admin" 
--admin-email="user@example.com" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="admin123" 
--language="en_US" 
--currency="USD"
--timezone="America/Chicago" 
--use-rewrites="1" 
--backend-frontname="admin"
```

Then run setup upgrade command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

from your Magento2 root directory

Answer (score 0):

```
magento setup:install
```

[image]

[image]

You can find more informations [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html) and [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html)